# How does logback rollover work for the last file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am new to logback and trying to understand how it works.

I have create logback-spring.xml and added below RollingFIleAppender

I want to rollover if the file reaches 10MB... Say between 26th April 12:00 AM and 26th April 9 PM, rollover happens everytime the file reaches 10MB, but if the size of the file current log file is 5 MB and it never increases, will it rollover the next day?

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs\logFile.html</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logs\logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.html</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 50MB -->
        <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}%thread%level%logger%line%msg</pattern>
      </layout>         
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        <appender-ref ref="milliroller"/>
    </root>
```

Example

```
logFile.html               ->            Size of this file at 26th April 9 PM is 5 MB and 
                                         size does not increase until 26th April 11:59 
                                         PM...This file is is not rolled over until 
                                         then...Will it be rolled over to next day? i.e 
                                         logFile.2023-04-27.0.html
logFile.2023-04-26.0.html
logFile.2023-04-26.1.html
logFile.2023-04-26.2.html
```